# $\mathbb{P}(\{X>a\}) = 1 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X)>a$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

The implication

$$\mathbb{P}(\{X>a\}) = 1 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X)>a$$

seems obviously true to me, but I can't nail a half-way rigorous proof of it.  (Coming up with a counterexample seems to me even less feasible, of course.)

Is it in fact true?

Assuming that the answer is yes, or that not-too-onerous can be added to make the implication true, does this theorem have a name?

Comment: If $X$ has density function $f(x)=1/x^2$ on $[1,\infty)$ (and zero elsewhere), then we certainly have $P(x>1)=1$ (since it's a continuous distribution). Yet the expected value $E(X)$ does not exist, since it would be $\int_1^{\infty}(1/x)dx.$ But perhaps you mean to assume $E(X)$ exists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trafficking in proababilities here, $P(X > a) = 1$ means $X \gt a$ a.e, so
$$E(X) = \int_\Omega X\, dP > \int_\Omega a\, dP = a.$$

You can also do this.  Since $X > a$ a.e., you have $F_X(a) = 0$.
Thus,

$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,dF_x(x) = \int_a^\infty x\,dF_x(x)
> \int_a^\infty a\,dF_X(x) = a. $$